# What is the expected number of additional rolls of dice to get $n$ even numbers consecutively, if we got $m$ ($0\le m<n$) even numbers already?

Tags: probability, expected-value, dice

Basically how many times we should roll the dice to get $n$ even numbers back to back? But the catch is we have already started the trial and we got $m$ even numbers, where $m \ge 0$ and $m < n$.

That means I have rolled already $m$ times and I got even number every time. Now what is the expected number of additional rolls that require to get $n$ consecutive even  numbers?

Comment: When you say “How many”, do you mean “What is the expected number of”?

Comment: Can this be solved with the given information? Like, don't we need to know  how many trials have been done before

Comment: How many times? That is variable of course, so there is no answer on that. Don' t you something as: "...can we expect...?"

Comment: Sorry , I mean to ask  "What is the expected number of ? "

Comment: Do you know how to solve this starting from scratch (meaning you haven’t rolled any even numbers yet)?

Comment: I don't know Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this number $e(m,n)$, and also set $e(n,n)=0$ (if you've just had a run of $n$
consecutive evens you need no more rolls).

Conditioning on the next roll gives, for $0\le m<n$,
$$e(m,n)=1+\frac{e(m+1,n)+e(0,n)}{2}.$$
Subtracting two consecutive instances gives
$$e(m+1,n)-e(m,n)=\frac{e(m+2,n)-e(m+1,n)}{2}$$
for $0\le m\le n-2$.
Therefore
$$e(m+1,n)-e(m,n)= 2^mA$$
with $A=e(1,n)-e(0,n)$. Adding these up gives
$$e(n,n)-e(0,n)=1-e(0,n)=A(1+2+4+\cdots+2^{n-1}).$$
This provides a relation between $e(1,n)$ and $e(0,n)$ and from the initial relation
we get another:
$$e(0,n)=1+\frac{e(1,n)+e(0,n)}{2}.$$
These should be enough to find $e(0,n)$, $e(1,n)$ and so then $A$ and all the $e(m,n)$.

Comment: Thank you very much @AnginaSeng. Now I can solve these type of questions in this method.After solving the above equations I got the final answer as $e(m,n) = 2^{n+1} - 2^{m+1}$.